# How to Compress a JSONObject send it over Http in Android?

Tags: android, json, servlets, compression

I am sending a `JSONObject` to my Webserver from an `Android client` using the code from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android). Reproducing code here

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;  // = 10 seconds
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
    postMessage.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

**My Question**

How to do best compression on `JSONObject` before sending it to server and how to decompress it on Server (I am using `Java Servlets`)?

Comment: Is the amount of data so large that you really need to use compression?

Comment: @Squonk I may need to do some analysis to quantify the size of data I am sending across the server but the round trip from client to server and back is taking about 2 minutes 49 seconds.

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html? You'd probably need to use `HttpURLConnection` rather than `DefaultHttpClient` however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html If you are using Gingerbread or later HttpURLConnection automatically adds gzip compression:

> In Gingerbread, we added transparent response compression.
>   HttpURLConnection will automatically add this header to outgoing
>   requests, and handle the corresponding response:
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip

Your webserver would then need to handle gzip compression.

Edit:
[Serve Gzipped content with Java Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862908/serve-gzipped-content-with-java-servlets)

Edit 2:
Gzip compression using DefaultHttpClient [Enabling GZip compression with HttpClient](http://forrst.com/posts/Enabling_GZip_compression_with_HttpClient-u0X)

```
private static final String HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING = "Accept-Encoding";
private static final String ENCODING_GZIP = "gzip";

final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, parameters);

client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
  public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) {
    // Add header to accept gzip content
    if (!request.containsHeader(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING)) {
      request.addHeader(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING, ENCODING_GZIP);
    }
  }
});

client.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
  public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
    // Inflate any responses compressed with gzip
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    final Header encoding = entity.getContentEncoding();
    if (encoding != null) {
      for (HeaderElement element : encoding.getElements()) {
        if (element.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ENCODING_GZIP)) {
          response.setEntity(new InflatingEntity(response.getEntity()));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Edit 3:
Here is another Stackoverflow question regarding the gzipping of post contents [GZip POST request with HTTPClient in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153484/gzip-post-request-with-httpclient-in-java).  You will need to manually gzip the data before posting it, since the normal http/gzip operation is the server sending gzipped content to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Android 2.2 and DefaultHTTPClient

Comment: Thanks for Edit2. This looks like code for accepting Gzip response from the server. I am looking at compression on the Android Client before sending the data to server.

Comment: I have asked a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414987/what-header-should-be-used-for-sending-gzip-compressed-json-from-android-client

Comment: The "gzip" header isnt transmitted to the server; Im using wireshark and I see no trace of "gzip"...

Comment: The question is asking about compression from Android client to Server, but this answer is about adding Accept-Encoding to enable compression from Server to client. This doesn't answer the question -- or am I missing something?

Comment: I found this file that contained an action example how to compress the request body https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-http/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/http/HttpClientTransport.java