# What header should be used for sending GZIP compressed JSON from Android Client to Server?

Tags: android, json, servlets, http-headers, gzip

This question is extension to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402813/how-to-compress-a-jsonobject-send-it-over-http-in-android). I am using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153945/932307) reproduced below to GZIP compress a `JSONObject`.

```
String foo = "value";
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;

try {
    gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
    gzos.write(foo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} finally {
    if (gzos != null) try { gzos.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {};
}

byte[] fooGzippedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I am using a `DefaultHttpClient` to send this compressed JSONObject to server(the code is in my control).

**My Question**

What header should I use in my `request`? I am using `request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");` for sending JSON to server?

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1573391/181714) Short answer would be `request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");`

Comment: @Audrius  ok, should I delete the question or a diffrent question title will  help the community?

Comment: I flagged it so it will be closed and, as you said, alternative title will help somebody else.

Comment: @Audrius if you wish to answer, add it, I will accpect or you may edit my answer.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal How are you sending the compressed byte[] in a POST request?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To inform the server that you are sending gzip-encoded data, send the [Content-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) header, not [Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3).

Comment: If you wonder also how to specify that the json text is UTF-8: set the content type to `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 21):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1576513/181714) answer shows you that you need to set a header indicating that you are sending data compressed:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
request.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
// ...
httpClient.execute(request);
```

The answer also shows how to deal with the incoming compressed data.

Comment: Sorry @Audrius, I hope you will appreciate Michael Hampton stand more merit, therefore I am accepting it in greater good of community.

Answer (score 5):

- `Content-Type:application/json` - tells what type of content data in the http call
- `Content-Encoding: gzip` - tells what compression being used.

`application/json` or `text/xml` or other type can be compressed as gzip and sending to receiver and with `Content-Type` header only, receiver will identify the incoming data is of type `json/xml/text` and then convert back to object of type json/xml/text.

With `Content-Encoding` header only receiver will identify the incoming data is getting gzip compressed. Then receiver required to decompress the incoming data and use it.