# Adding gzip to spring embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gzip, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm trying to add gzip compression to my server (reading and writing) I've tried it with (spring boot):

```
server.tomcat.compression=on
server.tomcat.compressableMimeTypes=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

but when my client sends :

```
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        gzip.write(content.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8")));
        gzip.close();
```

with headers :

```
        Accept-Encoding" - "gzip"
        "Content-Encoding" -  "gzip"
```

The data reaches the service still compressed.
What did I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an existing filter :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pjl-comp-filter</groupId>
        <artifactId>pjl-comp-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

And added a bean for it (new CompressingFilter())

If anyone had the same problem or knows why it didn't work with the spring boot configuration I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your client is sending the correct `Content-Encoding` header, without it Tomcat won't know that decompression is needed. See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423361/1526192).

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 1.2? Perhaps you could share a project that replicates the issue.

Comment: I'm using spring boot 1.2.4 (spring version 4.1.6)