# how use big json data with HTTPoison?

Tags: json, elixir, httpoison

Sorry, I am using Phonenix Framwork / Elixir, I need use HTTPoison with a large json in PUT method, but always send a response error, What i can do ?

This is mi function code

```
def download(json, conn) do
 HTTPoison.start()
    "url"
    |> HTTPoison.post(json, [{"Content-Type", "application/json"}], recv_timeout: 800_000)
    |> case do
      {:ok, response} -> result = response.body
      {:ok, result}
      conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/pdf")
      |> put_resp_header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=LB.pdf")
      |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(:ok, result)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you simplify this?  You are doing 2 things here: making a post request and sending a pdf response.  Does the post request work? (I don't see a put request).  Does the download work if you save the result of the post and try sending that?

Comment: @Everett Yes this work it, but with json small or medium, and i am using this for create a pdf file with a service in remote server, the problem is with a json large...
i newbie

Comment: how large is large?
If it is a size restriction causing the problem, perhaps gzip could help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414987/what-header-should-be-used-for-sending-gzip-compressed-json-from-android-client