# Serve an already-gzipped response from a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gzip

I have a gzipped JSON resource in my application that I want to serve up via a servlet. Browsers disagree on exactly why, but none of them will actually load my content. Does something look wrong with this code?

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setStatus(200);

        InputStream in = <get an input stream to my gzipped data>;

        resp.setIntHeader("Content-Length", in.available());
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

        out.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
        out.close();

        resp.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is available in the link in the accepted answer in this thread - [Serve Gzipped content with Java Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862908/serve-gzipped-content-with-java-servlets).

This includes a working example from the O'Reilly site.

However I would question your need for introducing this cross curling concern and gzip the contents manually. Assuming you are using Apache or a fork thereof, I would suggest you look at [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) it is configurable and powerful and releases you from the need to write boilerplate code for gzipping responses.